# Why did the query tasks keeps running and exceeds the longest allowing query time set in Apache IoTDB version 1.2.2?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently use version 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB and there are 20,000 time series data stored in total. I use `show queries` and found that there are 35,000 query tasks happening (which should not be that much in my case). The time generated first has already run for more than 13,683 seconds, but I already set the longest query time to 10 seconds and it should be stopped if executing longer. Why is this? I had this problem in the past, so I upgraded the version from 1.0.1. Maybe my IoTDB execution window is always open, but the query time of this interface should not be accumulated to that high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query task cannot be normally executed if the duration exceeds that much. You can use "KILL ALL QUERIES" first to stop all continuing tasks in Apache IoTDB. If this statement does not take effect, then this may because the query logic is not closed in coding, and low version of IoTDB and high concurrency may cause blocking. If you already updated your IoTDB version, you can check whether you updated the version thoroughly. To upgrade IoTDB version, the `lib` directory files also needs to be replaced with the new version api. If you did not replace this, try to replace these files again and see fi the query tasks return normal.